# Is it possible to use custom (non-circle) buffer shapes?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, buffer

I have a shapefile containing points. I'd like to replace each point by the same shape, centered around the point, like the "Buffer" tool with shapes other than circles. How can I do that?

Comment: what type of shape?  square? something else?

Comment: What I had in mind was a rotated square. But I suppose that if you can do it with a rotated square, you should be able to do it with any shape, right?

Comment: do you need the rotated square for cartographic purpose or to do some GIS analysis ?

Comment: GIS analysis. The squares correspond to parallel lines on the ground, which are not necessarily oriented North-South.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more than 3 years, we have various options, but let me suggest [Shape Tools](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shapetools/).

One option is **N-sided polygon**, which I used to create a rotated square as below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, that sounds like a great solution!

Comment: @F.X. Thank you! Honestly I was surprised receiving so quick response.